# What is the significance of the red outline in a failed Coded UI test screenshot?

Tags: mstest, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to debug a VS2010 Coded UI test which is supposed to find and select a particular row in a WinTable.  The test passes on my local machine, but fails on our nightly test run (which executes on a remote VM).  The MSTest framework includes a screenshot of the UI at the time of failure with the failure report, which clearly shows that the wrong row of the WinTable was selected.  HOWEVER, in the screenshot the CORRECT control is outlined with a thick red border that is definitely not part of our regular UI.

I tried searching MSDN (and of course this forum) but could not find any explanation of what the red line signifies.  I'm hopeful the answer will help me get to the bottom of my failing test since it consistently outlines the control I believe should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge script is finding the table control correctly but does not find related rows/columns to select the record properly. The reason for this could be

- If code is searching using row index then record might not be available on same index
- Table must be visible but window is not yet idle due to which it might not have allowed script to interact with table properly
- Table must be still rendering when script tried to interact with it
- Window might have been opened in restored mode and due to which Row/Column which script is looking for might be off-screen

I would suggest to implement wait logic before selecting the row. The wait loop should continue till window gets idle and rendering of table gets completed.

Hope it helps!